# How do you align the vertical center of text to the vertical center of an image?

Tags: css

How do you align the **vertical center** of text to the vertical center of an image? It appears to me that the following code only makes the **baseline** of the text align to the vertical center of the image. I would like to have a physical sense of balance.

http://jsfiddle.net/tokyotech/TBbJF/

**Output**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.png" />
<span>Foo</span>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  font-size: 3em;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given the text a vertical align of middle. Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the span css and it should work.

Comment: This solves the particular case. How about the case where your text is not eveloped? For example, `<img src="image.png" />Foo`. Or is it not possible to vertically center in that case?

Comment: I don't see how you can do that. One way *(which I believe is deprecated)* might be to add it as a content to a table cell using `<td valign="middle">`